# hide the android phonegap application but not exit

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am doing a project in android phonegap.Here I want to show notification to user who has logged in the application like a background service.ie user should get notification in the notification area even if he/she closed the application.Now Iam using local notification in my application [Status bar notification](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification) and the user will get notification in the notification area.But I came to know that javascript file is not running in background.I have tried [Push Notifications](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap) tutorial.But it is not running in background.Now my question is

Is there any way to hide the application,but actually the application (javascript) file is running and the user get notification?

Is there any function in phonegap like moveTaskToBack(true) in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use push notifications. As part of properly implementing a push notification listener your app will start a service which will be able to respond to push notifications when it isn't running.

https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: Thanks simon for your reply.But I have followed the [link](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/).But not working for me.But when i add the code **@Override public void onBackPressed() { moveTaskToBack(true); return; }** to main activity with local status bar notification, it works fine now.